# Can not start Chrome in Headless Mode

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, nosuchelementexception, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to use the `Chrome Headless` mode on Selenium Webdriver to test a script
with different arguments I get
`NoSuchElementException` - when finding by xpath
`chrome not reachable` - webdriverexception
`chrome failed to start` -

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless","--disable-gpu");
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

this is the initialization.

No problem with the xpath as it is working on Normal mode.

- Chrome version 60
- Selenium 3.5.0
- Chrome driver 2.32

Comment: Have you checked with Selenium to see whether they support headless mode? Because it sounds like they do not....

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet yes they do. I am not sure what I am missing. But other people seems to got it to work.

Comment: please provide the URL and Html, use wait for element to locate

Comment: URL - on local host -> https://localhost:8443/sbreport/login find element is working on other browsers Chrome normal, Firefox, IE and PhantomJS so i don't think it is find element related. However I've tried with different arguments and it seems I can not start the Chrome headless correctly. Now I am getting Chrome not reachable, Chrome failed to start as well

Comment: How will i access ur localhost can i give u sample example,are u unable to access Chrome in Headless mode?

Comment: Seems like this is similar to my issue - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=878

Comment: Yes you are correct. The problem - Can not access Chrome in Headless mode

Comment: https://codeshare.io/aJdogX - this is the code sample